# How do I edit code on multiple computers using github? Is there a way to have multiple paths in one project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

So essentially I have a project on GitHub that I edit on both my personal computer and my school laptop. Except for the fact that every time I commit an update I have to update the path? Is there any way to have two simultaneous python paths in for example the JSON file? Maybe some sort of gitignore file or smth(not that good at GitHub nor git).

Btw the project is in python 3.

Comment: keep files in a common folder in the codebase ?

Comment: In your `launch.json` work with variables or don't commit `launch.json` and keep an edited version with the needed paths on each machine

Comment: which path are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called [github for desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) that allows you to store a local copy of the repository you're working on, then when you're done you can click **commit** changes and then **push them**, it will submit them to the cloud. You need to do this for every computer you want to work your project from. Also, you can watch [this](https://youtu.be/77W2JSL7-r8) to see how to set it up!